# How to re-calculate items max-height on resize?

Tags: javascript

I am facing one problem, where I have created accordions/faq items which you can toggle (open & close) and switch to another one and close the previous one which works fine. But the issue here is if I resize my browser or change the orientation mode to landscape or portrait the max-height is not re-calculated.

I have created a function "accordionHeight" which works onClick but I am unable to pass the "item" to this function to re-calculate outside my click event.

Because the height will obviously only change on click. But I want it to re-calculate on rotate of the current open "item__box" but it's outside the scope.

I have a real example on Codepen instead of code.

My JS:

```
(() => {
    const accordion = document.querySelector('[bke-data="accordion"]');

    if (!accordion) {
        return;
    }

    const items = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

    const accordionHeight = (element, elementHeight) => {
        element.style.setProperty(`--max-height`, `${elementHeight}px`);
    };

    const toggleAccordion = (item) => {
        const itemBox = item.querySelector('.accordion__box');
        const itemBoxHeight = itemBox.scrollHeight;
        const openItems = accordion.querySelectorAll('.open');
        const itemsLength = openItems.length;
        const currentItem = item;

        // itemBox.style.setProperty(`--max-height`, `${itemBoxHeight}px`);

        accordionHeight(itemBox, itemBoxHeight);

        if (itemsLength) {
            openItems.forEach((item) => {
                item !== currentItem && item.classList.remove('open');
            });
        }

        item.classList.toggle('open');
    };

    items.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => toggleAccordion(item));
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', accordionHeight);
})();
```

Codepen full code + example: `https://codepen.io/Merdzanovich/pen/MWvaryG`

Answer (score 1):

Please, see below example of resize event handling.
**Note: Run snippet in full page mode**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onresize="myFunction()">

<p>Try to resize the browser window to display the windows height and width.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> this example will not work properly in IE8 and earlier. IE8 and earlier do not support the outerWidth/outerHeight propery of the window object.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var w = window.outerWidth;
  var h = window.outerHeight;
  var txt = "Window size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```